# cannot handle node JS delete request 404 error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server, backend

it does give me back the id , but it is not deleting it from the mongodb collection & frontend list , I keep getting a 404 error on the network dev tools tab....

NodeJS

```
  app.delete("/showlist-fromdb/:id", async (req, res) => {
      try {
     
        let uid = req.params.id.toString();
    
        List.deleteOne({ _id: uid });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
```

React:

```
export const deleteListing = async (idHolder) =>{
      /**DELETE METHOD */
      const options = {
        url: `http://localhost:5001/showlist-fromdb/:id${idHolder}`,
        method: 'DELETE',
        // data: idHolder
      };
      
      axios(options)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('A listing got deleted!')
      }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
      
      // axios.delete(`http://localhost:5001/showlist-fromdb/:id${idHolder}`)
  

}
```

Comment: I think the url should be `http://localhost:5001/showlist-fromdb/${idHolder}`

Comment: lol thank you, but it also didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

figured out the problem i forgot to add await before the delete command, thanks everyone